Posterior approximation following optimization methods
I'm trying to quantify the uncertainty in a high dimensional, and multimodal posterior space. We do not have a analytical solution for the forward model, and the forward model could be expensive to run. Because the gradient-free MCMC will take too long to converge and can't be parallelized, so I'm trying to avoid MCMC. What we can do is running gradient-free optimization in multi-threads. So I was wondering if there's a way to reconstruct or approximate the posterior with the ensembles of samples/steps in the optimization steps.
Here I demonstrate this question in a 2D case. The background colour represents the true posterior we are interested, and the yellow points are the samples. I run a simple optimisation with gradient descent here, just for demonstration purpose.

Obviously directly using the histogram will results in some over-dense region, which doesn't represent the posterior. Blue shadow shows the samples from the true posterior.

If we use all the optimization steps, also the same unbalanced density is there, of course. But is there a way to use the information we have now to estimate the posterior somehow? Any idea is appreciated.


Hi, welcome on Cross validated. If you are looking for an method approximating your posterior, mean-field variational bayes could be interesting. If you want a specific closed-form solution to your problem you will need to have conjugate priors, though. However, other types of factorizations are possible.

Thanks @MangnierLoïc for the reply. The mean-field variational method does look interesting, I will have a look.
